# Continously refreshing a matplotlib figure results in a slowdown

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code that displays a figure with two images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = np.zeros((400,400,3), dtype=np.uint8)
img2 = np.ones((400,400,3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255

f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)

counter = 0
while True:
    print('Counter=', counter)
    counter += 1
    axarr[0].imshow(img1)
    axarr[1].imshow(img2)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

The images are going to be regenerated at each iteration, and I want to continuously refresh the figure. The code works, but at each iteration it is slower and slower. I suspect there is some kind of leak, or at least something that I'm doing wrong.

But what?

Shall I call clf()? I tried, and it creates a new window at each iteration. Shall I call

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

and somehow release the newly created figure at each iteration? (but how, in this case?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `axarr[0].imshow(img1)`, a new image will be added to the axes. Try to clear at each iteration the images stored with `axarr[0].images = []` and `axarr[1].images = []` (or `axarr[0].images.clear()` and `axarr[1].images.clear()`).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work if I do : axarr[0].images.clear()

Comment: Is there any web site online to learn more about how resources are allocated within a figure etc.? I'm really struggling with this.

Comment: Eheh, I really have no idea. I learned it the hard way by exploring the attributes exposed by the axes object. For example, running `dir(axarr[0])` you'll be presented with a list of attributes. I know that `axarr[0].lines` is where lines are stored, `axarr[0].images` is where images are stored. Other notable attributes where things are stored are `collections` (for surfaces, line collections, contours plots), `patches`... Unfortunately, in this regard Matplotlib is pretty messy. :(

Comment: Thanks again. Exactly, these concepts should be explained I think and help people get the "philosophy" of matplotlib, which is powerful but its API is really rough. As often, people need to try many things and design their own personal documentation!